# Regex - how do I match this?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I've been trying hard to get this Regex to work, but am simply not good enough at this stuff apparently :(

[Regex - Trying to extract sources](https://regex101.com/r/ulO9GO/1/)

I thought this would work... I'm trying to get all of the content where:

1. It starts with ds://
2. Ends with either carriage return or line feed

That's it!  Essentially I'm going to then do a negative lookahead such that I can remove all content that is NOT conforming to above (in Notepad++) which allows for Regex search/replace.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for lines that contain the pattern, and mark them

   - Search menu > Mark
   - Find what: `ds://.*\R`
   - *check Regular expression*
   - *Check Mark the lines*
   - <kbd>Find all</kbd>
2. Remove the non marked lines

   - Search menu > Bookmark
   - Remove unmarked lines

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `\w` specifier to look for a word after the `ds://` in the look ahead. Removing that and altering the final specification from "zero or one carriage return, then zero or one newline" to "either a carriage return or a newline" in capture group should do it for you:

```
(?=ds:\/\/).*(?:\r|\n)
```

#### Update: Carriage return or Line feed group does not need to be captured.

#### Update 2: The following regex will actually work for your proposed use case in the comments, matching everything *but* the pattern you described in the question.

```
^(?:(?!ds:\/\/.*(?:\r|\n)).)*$
```

Comment: Awesome.  That does find all of them.  I would have thought changing ?= to ?! would have made it the inverse (i.e., finding everything else)... I must be missing something

Comment: If you goal is to find everything else (not *entirely* clear from your question) then you would have to use a "negative lookaround" to *kind of* do what you want. Take a look at [this detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/4362829) for more info. Let me know if you want me to take a crack at it.

Comment: Updated Regex as it does not need to capture \n or \r group.

Answer (score 0):

You regex `(?=ds:\w+).*\r?\n?` does not match because in the content there is `ds://` and `\w` does not match a forward slash. To make your regex work you could change it to:

`(?=ds://\w+).*\r?\n?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nwIsIJ/1) which can be shortened to `ds://.*\R?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HVlbSM/1/)

Note that you don't have to escape the forward slash.

If you want to do a find and replace to keep the lines that contain `ds://` you could use a negative lookahead:

**Find what**

`^(?!.*ds://).*\R?`

**Replace with**

Leave empty

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!.*ds://`) Negative lookahead to assert the string does not contain `ds://`
- `.*` Match any character 0+ times
- `\R?` An optional unicode newline sequence to also match the last line if it is not followed by a newline

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Psmvh/1)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, Andrew:

**Regex:** `ds:\/\/.*`

**Link:** https://regex101.com/r/ulO9GO/2

Let me know if any question.

Comment: Does not answer the question.